# Make a Circular ListContourPlot With Data at r increments

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I have a List of Temperature Values ranging from r=0, to rmax at different value of z. Currently, the only contour plot I can make is an r-z plot. I have been able reverse the data to produce a plot that ranges from {-rmax, rmax}, but I think it would be more effective to show an r-theta plot at z=10. At each r, the Temperature value should be identical from 0 to 2pi, giving me perfect rings. Since, I do not have any theta values, what is the best was for me to create this plot?

[image: r-z Contour Plot]

edit: I have created some data similar to the situation I have. The numbers arent exactly the same, but I tried to replicate them as well as possible.

```
    rmax = 6;
    zmax = 10;

    T = Table[0, {r, 1, rmax}, {z, 1, zmax}];

    T[[All, All]] = {{482.076, 482.075, 482.070, 482.0625, 482.051, 
482.038, 482.023, 482.005, 481.9873, 481.967}, {482.084, 482.083, 
482.0784, 482.0705, 482.059, 482.0464, 482.030, 482.013, 481.995, 
481.978}, {482.109, 482.107, 482.102, 482.094, 482.083, 482.069, 
482.053, 482.035, 482.017, 481.999}, {482.149, 482.147, 482.142, 
482.134, 482.122, 482.108, 482.0915, 482.072, 482.051, 
482.031}, {482.204, 482.202, 482.197, 482.189, 482.177, 482.162, 
482.144, 482.123, 482.099, 482.074}, {482.274, 482.272, 482.267, 
482.259, 482.247, 482.231, 482.212, 482.189, 482.161, 482.130}};

    ListContourPlot[Transpose[T]]
```

Comment: Where's your data?

Comment: Can you provide the code? I am not sure if I understand the question... If you just want to plot rings, you could use `ParametricPlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I understood you correctly, you have for each value of `z` a list of temperatures. Since you haven't provided data, let us create some fake ones

```
data = Table[Sin[r]*(2 - Cos[z]), {z, 0., 1/2, 1/19}, {r, 0, Pi/2, Pi/(2*19)}];
ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the only missing piece is that you have to make a coordinate transformation. `ContourPlot` will always use Cartesian coordinates `x` and `y`, but what you want to have is for each `{x,y}` the radius. Centering the origin in the middle, this is easy because you are just calculating the Euclidean distance like in school

$$ r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

Indeed, this formula is part of the transformation [to polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

Since you have only a list of temperatures for some `r`, we will interpolate the places in between and then, we can put this together and use `ContourPlot` as usual. Then you have it, a `Manipulate` that gives you the contour plot you like for a chosen `z`:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{ip = ListInterpolation[data[[z]]]},
  ContourPlot[
   With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, ip[Min[20, r]]],
   {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 20],
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}
   ]
  ],
 {z, 1, Length[data], 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I appreciate all your help :D

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly a bit resource intensive:

Some data dependent on `r`:

```
data = Table[r^2 - Sin[2 Pi r]^2, {r, -3, 3, 0.01}];
```

Generate the full array:

```
array = Table[{i/100, j/100, 
    data[[Round[Sqrt[i^2 + j^2 + 300]]]]}, {i, -200, 200}, {j, -200, 
    200}];
ListContourPlot[Flatten[array, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: may be a little better to use `Interpolation` instead of `Round`

Comment: @george2079 You're right, halirutan used `Interpolation` now, so I'll just leave it. Can't be bothered to alter anyway if the OP doesn't even come back to update his own question.